# how to do like this in flutter with these curved?

Tags: flutter, dart

how to do like this in flutter with these curved

[image]

I am new in flutter and I want to learn how to do like this I tried to make it using stack but it didn't show like the image!

I want to learn how to do curve in design !
please help me!

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html

Comment: Check this https://github.com/rafalbednarczuk/curved_navigation_bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'flutter shape maker' to create custom paint shape (saves lots of time but requires login to copy code). Use stack to put circular image on top of it.

Tool i used: https://fluttershapemaker.com/

Use custom paint widget

```
    child: CustomPaint(
       size: Size(WIDTH,(WIDTH*0.625).toDouble()), //You can Replace [WIDTH] with your desired width for Custom Paint and height will be calculated automatically
       painter: RPSCustomPainter(),
    ),
```

Custom paint code

```
class RPSCustomPainter extends CustomPainter{
  
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    
    

  Paint paint_0 = new Paint()
      ..color = Color.fromARGB(255, 252, 107, 107)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = 1.0;
     
         
    Path path_0 = Path();
    path_0.moveTo(0,size.height*0.5000000);
    path_0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.0631250,size.height*0.5000000,size.width*0.0625000,size.height*0.4400000);
    path_0.cubicTo(size.width*0.0625000,size.height*0.1400000,size.width*0.3137500,size.height*0.1410000,size.width*0.3125000,size.height*0.4400000);
    path_0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.3131250,size.height*0.5000000,size.width*0.3750000,size.height*0.5000000);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width,size.height*0.5000000);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width,size.height);
    path_0.lineTo(0,size.height);

    canvas.drawPath(path_0, paint_0);
  
    
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
  
}
```

Adjust values based on your needs

[Shape will look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMLoc.png)